# Sound, additive principle or not? How to prove?

Tags: acoustics, intensity

If we have $N$ sound sources with $L_1, L_2,...$ with intensities $I_1, I_2,...$. How to prove that
$I_{total}= I_1 + I_2 + ... $ but $L_{total}$ is NOT $L_1 + L_2 + ... $

Comment: If anything, it's amplitudes that should add, [not intensities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control). What does $L$ denote?

Comment: It denotes sound level

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level)?

Comment: [link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Sound/db.html#c1)

Comment: So yes. You should edit clarifications like this into your question do people don't have to rely on comments, which can be ephemeral. But to answer your question, additive levels would mean pressure behaved in a way that violates energy conservation, if you think of pressure as energy density.

Comment: You can use linearity of wave equation to prove it or even use the given formula for intensity calculation and prove that it is linear.